# Android emulator(Android Studio) Home button not working and giving logcat - I/WindowManager: Not starting activity because user setup is in progress

Tags: android, emulation, android-homebutton, home-button, android-studio-2.0

Started emulator from Android Studio and it's Home button not working.
When I press Home button, in logcat I can see

```
I/WindowManager: Not starting activity because user setup is in progress: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 (has extras) }
```

And same happens(same logcat) when keyboard shortcut(keyboard Home button) is used.

I restarted emulator and my machine several times, but no help.

**The thing I want to achieve is killing my app** by Home button Long Press

Emulator details:

```
Name: 2_7_QVGA_slider_API_23_L
CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a)
Path: C:\Users\sh56000\.android\avd\2_7_QVGA_slider_API_23_L.avd

Target: Android 6.0 (API level 23)
Skin: 240x320
SD Card: 100M
Snapshot: no
hw.dPad: no
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: 2.7in QVGA slider
vm.heapSize: 16
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Generic
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
hw.keyboard.lid: yes
hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8
tag.id: default
hw.camera.back: none
hw.mainKeys: yes
AvdId: 2_7_QVGA_slider_API_23_L
hw.camera.front: none
hw.lcd.density: 120
runtime.scalefactor: auto
avd.ini.displayname: 2.7 QVGA slider API 23 L
snapshot.present: no
hw.device.hash2: MD5:89d*************55e42054c413
hw.ramSize: 512
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Default
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
disk.dataPartition.size: 200M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, there are 3 solutions for this issue: (2 & 3 need adb drivers or terminal app)

1. Switch to guest and come back

> Settings->Users->Guest (or)
>
> Swipe down the notification bar and click on profile icon on the left
> top

2. Start the initial setup and complete it or skip it

> adb shell am start -n
> com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardActivity

3. Give below command to mark that setup is done

> adb shell
>
> $ settings --user 0 put secure user_setup_complete 1

Answer (score 2):

If the above doesn't work, try:

```
adb shell settings --user 0 put secure user_setup_complete 1
adb shell settings --user 0 put secure tv_user_setup_complete 1
adb shell settings --user 0 put global device_provisioned 1
```

No reboot needed!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on my Nexus 9 (Android 6) after I did some "clean up" (deleting cache and app data). Seems I've "cleaned up" too much.

The command which fixed it for me:

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardTestActivity
```

The Activity name is slightly different (changes in Android 6 I guess).
I ran through the setup again (had to type in WIFI password again) and skipped the "restore apps" part. Afterwards everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 1):

### Cause

This general error caused by a missing configuration value (damaged main config). *E.g.: This can be happen on a real phone too when the phone turned off suddenly by an unplugged battery.*

In this case you can't reach the quick settings menu on some devices.

### Fixing

1. Enable the USB debugging on your phone, and connect to a PC
2. Run Setup Wizard by `adb` and wait until it appears, but **do nothing** on your phone

   ```sh
   adb shell am start -n 'com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardActivity'
   ```

   If it's can't start, because there's missing intent, you should run this:

   ```sh
   adb shell am start -n 'com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardTestActivity'
   ```
3. Set the setup complete flag:

   ```sh
   adb shell settings --user 0 put secure user_setup_complete 1
   ```
4. Restart phone

   ```sh
   adb reboot
   ```

Done!

*This method will not overwrite/cleanup the current settings (e.g. Wifi access points).*

Answer (score 0):

try restart the setup wizard if it can help

> adb shell am start -n
>   com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardActivity

I have similar issue today on my Cyanogenmod 13. and re-run the wizard did the fix for me.

Comment: I got Activity class does not exist trying that

Answer (score 0):

It might be a different situation but here is what helped. Wnen on Android Q, home button would not work, but when I dragged the ask google desktop widget up (don't ask me why I did that), this revealed the apps drawer. When here, home button does work by showing desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my Android emulator (Google Pixel 2). Wiping the data in the Android Studio AVD manager fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the virtual device with a cold boot from AVD Manager fixed it for me.